# Is it possible to know which will get the next pending block?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, mining

Is it possible to predict which miner will mine the next pending block on ethereum mainnet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.

With that said, a miner who has a majority of the hash rate of the network has the highest chance of mining the next block.